# Assigning a docker container a static private ip to access it without port forwarding

Tags: docker

My laptop has an ip address of 10.0.0.128 on the local network. I'm trying to assign a docker container it's own ip address within the same range(?) for example, 10.0.0.135. In order to do this, I tried creating a new bridged network in docker; however, I keep encountering an error.

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 255.255.255.0/24 --gateway 10.0.0.1 testnetwork
no matching subnet for gateway 10.0.0.1
```

I've looked at a couple of other examples, and have only got it to work when specifying an ip starting with 172, like in the following example.

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 testnetwork
docker run -d --net=testnetwork --ip=172.25.3.3 nginx
```

But I'm still unable to access the nginx server directly with the ip, and have to use port forwarding instead. Is there a way to assign a docker container an ip that I can use to access the container without port forwarding?

Comment: This won't work, docker creates a bridged network that is routed via your host routing table. The network needs to know how to route to this IP and it can't when you've used the same network/mask.

Comment: Is there a work around to achieve a similar result? Is there possibly a way to forward all ports instead of manually specifying which ports to forward when first running the container? I wanted to assign the container its own ip so that I could attempt to have access to all ports.

Comment: You can remove network isolation with `--net=host` which means it will see and act as if it's directly on the network interface(s) of the docker host.

Comment: Removing network isolation with that flag worked for me, and I am now able to access the server through the docker host interface. What are the limitations of working like this? If I have multiple containers running without network isolation, would those containers all share the same ip? I ran three containers, two nginx servers that both use port 80, and an ssh server that uses port 22. The first nginx server and the ssh server worked without any problems; however, I noticed that the second nginx server would exit after a few seconds. Is this because both nginx servers run on the same port?

Comment: When you remove network isolation, the network perspective is identical to running the process outside of the container. So if multiple webservers would conflict outside of the container, then they will face identical issues if each container is run with `--net=host`.